# Why are some Shannon's limit plots exponential rather than logarithmic?

Tags: noise, power-spectral-density, snr, capacity

[image]

This diagram again. This is clearly not the shape of $\log_2(1+SNR)$ but I very frequently see this instead of this:

[image]

But this is also a stupid diagram because it doesn't cross at the origin.

Also why do the modulation techniques veer away from $\log_2(1+SNR)$, they should stay on the curve and then get suddenly capped at their spectral efficiencies.

Comment: The upper graph clearly IS the shape of $log_2(1+SNR)$. Why do you think it's not ?

Comment: @Hilmar https://imgur.com/a/DLHhKPb because that's the shape

Comment: @LewisKelsey the question was why do *you* think it's not? Seriously, insert the definition of dB into log(1+SNR), and come to your own conclusions, instead of citing other pictures!

Comment: @MarcusMüller well actually I typed that in desmos to illustrate what I was expecting, so that's my picture, but that's it, dB is logarithmic which I forgot about, thanks for the reminder. This is the answer

Comment: Morale of the story: read the axis labels!

Comment: @Hilmar The mis-spelling of the word  "moral" in your comment above has definitely reduced my morale today :-)

Comment: I should have a nice cold Moor-Ale tonight!

Comment: @MarcusMüller yeah so I had to use semilogx on matlab to be able to visualise it

Comment: @MarcusMüller so the modulation schemes veer away because its constrained with a PDF but why do you need to constrain the modulation schemes like this, in BPSK using an equal probability of selecting 1 or - 1. What does this model?

Comment: Short answer: mutual information over any useful symmetric linear channel is maximized by equidistribution of the input probabilities. This applies especially to the BI-AWGN channel. You can see that by thinking about the output of the channel: Which input distribution leads to maximum output entropy, assuming (and that's usually a given) independent noise?